# How to have a directive template keep element content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add `ng-click` to a button. My HTML:

`<button class="btn">clicky</button>`

And the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('btn', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="onClick()"></button>'
  };
});
```

It removes `clicky` from the element.

Transclude doesn't help. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Just to clarify, both `ng-transclude` in the template/element and `transclude: true` in the directive are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add    `ng-transclude` in template.

```
template: '<button ng-click="onClick()" ng-transclude></button>'
```

Comment: what are  you getting as a result ??